# Hybris how to have different customers by website with same uid?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

We want to have separate customers in a hybris instance with 4 websites.
"Separate" means that :

- It must be possible to create a customer with the same "uid" on the 4
  websites. Currently isn't possible because "uid" is unique.
- The addresses of customers must be separate too...
- Orders must be separate, but already done by hybris with
  personnalization

It is possible to customize Hybris in order to have in the same tenant/DB multiple users with the same ID but in different sites?

In the case that this is possible, which are the steps (in broad terms) needed to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution would be:

1. create or register customer with appending site uid so resultant customer uid will be unique(customeruid+"_"+"siteuid")
2. during login user need to put only customerid so this need customization and to customize it need to extend CoreAuthenticationProvider and change it to proper user.